# How to enable intellisense's auto completion that complete the word when adding the next special symbol?

Tags: visual-studio, autocomplete, intellisense

I work with visual studio community and Unity.
Not a long time ago I could start the begening of a word, having visual on the prediction, then type a special symbol as "=" and the auto-completion wrote correctly the full word and the "=".
Now adding the "=" just mess the result.
Something has change ?

Comment: Is there any update? Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here:)

Comment: problem still here, I update VS often. I will adapt and hope it change back.

Comment: Ok, you can also report this to [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=problem).

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if you didn’t update Visual Studio or add some **extensions**, tools and components, IntelliSense will not change. If you can provide some detailed reproducible steps, it will be helpful for us to check.

**Some suggestions:**

Please try to restart Visual Studio or your machine and try again. Go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > General and make sure the specific configurations are set. Follow this [*guide*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2019#reset-settings) and reset VS settings(select General on step 4). Clear your project cache, and also try to test in a newly created file/project.